# Using includes / joins

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have a Proposal model and a Signature model.

Proposal has many signatures and Signature belongs to proposal

My relationships work fine when I select a single Proposal, but when I do a Proposal.search and return multiple proposals, I can't access signatures.

I want to sort my proposals by signatures count, so I tried this:

```
Proposal.find(:all, :limit => 3, :include => [:signatures])
```

Now when I debug(@proposals) I do see the corresponding signatures. How do I access them and write an :order => signatures.count ?

I'm not very familiar with includes / joins ...so let me know if I'm going about this the wrong way. Thanks.

Comment: did you mean to say that you "do NOT see the corresponding signatures"?

Comment: He sees the corresponding signatures because :include properly includes the associated signatures, but just does a SELECT * - so it won't include any virtual count() columns.

Comment: when I include I DO see them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`:include` is used when you will need to access the signatures later. If all you need is the count of associated signatures for sorting, then you do not need `:include`.

I don't especially like the following, but it seems to work:

```
Proposal.find(:all,
              :limit => 3,
              :joins => :signatures,
              :group => 'proposals.id',
              :order => 'count(proposals.id) desc')
```

First, the `:joins` parameter means that for each Proposal record you will get another row in the output for each associated Signature. The `:group` parameter combines those rows into one, but only after the `:order` parameter sorts based on the number of rows for each proposal.id (and hence number of signatures).

I suspect there is a better way, but this seems to work.

Answer (score 2):

To get you familiar with using includes vs. joins, have a look at the [Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/181-include-vs-joins) that's dedicated to it.  The reason you can't order by signatures.count is because you're not selecting a column (or virtual column) that contains that information.

You're going to want a combination of :select and :join to get what you want.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest using ActiveRecord's [counter cache](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#M001835) feature. Add a `signatures_count` field to your Proposal model and then you can order doing:

```
Proposal.find(:all, :limit => 3, :include => [:signatures], :order => 'signatures_count DESC')
```

Check out the belongs_to API documentation linked above for more details. There's an older Railscasts episode on this [here](http://railscasts.com/episodes/23-counter-cache-column).